# In Spring Cloud, does micro-services read their configurations from Eureka or it only reads from config server?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFDYdslOvu8) to learn micro-services.

My questions is: Can micro-services read configuration from config service through Eureka, or they can only read configurations directly from config server ?

I am trying to configure and make a client read its configuration from eureka but with no success.

Comment: Eureka is a discovery system, not a configuration store

Comment: @spencergibb I know but can I configure the config server so that I can read configs via Eureka ? Or I've miss understood the architecture

Comment: configruation itself must be read from config server directly. But you can use Eureka to find your config server. It means that you don't need to specify the ip address of config server. Instead, if you specify service id for config server, your services will read config from your config server after resolving ip addresses of your config server through Eureka. Is it what you want to do ?

Comment: @yongsung.yoon Yes, this is exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following option in your `bootstrap.yml`

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
```

And you also need to specify the the service id of your config service.

```
spring.cloud.config.discovery.serviceId=xxxx
```

`serviceId` is usually the the application name.

If you do like above, your microservivces will try to find the address of config server via discovery service.

You can find more details [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#discovery-first-bootstrap).

Comment: I guess I'll have to make the config server register itself in Eureka, right ?

Comment: Yes. It can be done as the same way like other microservices.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, Your answer the accepted ;)